# Why was my co-workers answer deleted?

Tags: support

A co worker (who sits in front of me at work) signed into apple.stackexchange.com and posted an answer here: [Can the Kinect be used as a control interface for Mac OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/18733/1337)

His answer is no longer present.  I'm not sure if his account is still a member either.

My question is: Why was his answer removed?  I'm trying to encourage him to become an active user of this site.

Did I loose any rep for this?  I made an edit to his answer to include a picture but that was removed too.  If I was marked as a spammer in the past then I would suffer an "invsible" rep loss that won't appear in my history.  This happened once on StackOverflow.

I'm just asking for the mods to look into this and let me know (since I'm trying to be a good user)

Comment: Thank you for helping others find the site. There is no invisible rep or even a lag in showing when someone's reputation changes, so perhaps your past experience was due to the scheduled nature of reputation adjustments and bugs in the system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only deleted "answer" on the question is this one:

> I'm interested in seeing this but I don't have enough reputation to +1 this.
>   Just found this perusing the web. Looks very much like Kinect for Mac.
>   [link]

This isn't an answer to the question. Things posted as answers that aren't answers get deleted. I don't see anything with a picture. Your friend should be able to answer again, and this time, you can post a link to either their account or to the answer / edits and we can see what might have happened. Is there any chance you are linking to the incorrect question?

Comment: It's OK I thought there was a better answer there ...  Thanks